# why no relative path being used for @angular/core module import

Tags: angular, module

We use relative path to import our custome module OR services in angular 2 but why we never use relative path when import angular2 core modules like the below one.

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module loader (or module bundler) automatically looks for modules inside the `node_modules` folder, and because there's a module called `@angular` inside the `node_modules` folder, and a `core` module inside it, you can import it this way.